# Problem with yersinia command

Tags: kali-linux, command

I newly installed kali linux on windows on VMplayer. so fIsrt of all I installed yersinia tool which was successful. But when I tried to run a command yersinia -h, result was "you must be root to run yersinia 8.2.0.
I am a novice in kali linux so if you could explain me a simple way, that would be great.

Comment: If you're a novice, then Kali isn't the distro for you. It's for penetration testing and is meant for advanced users. If you can't tell what the issue is from that error message, then you need to change to a distro that's better for beginners like Ubuntu or Fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: you must be "root" (that is, the privileged user, superuser, administrator, etc.) to run that command.

Use the command `whoami` to print your username.  You can switch to the root user by typing `su -` and it will prompt you for the root user's password.

Answer (score 0):

You must be root to execute yersinia
run this command

```
sudo yersinia -h
```